# Docker fails to send a e-mail from command

Tags: docker, email

When I try to send email inside Docker container it displays this messages, but I never received email.

```
root@a036e48556e1:/# mail -s "Test docker, sendmail" erros@mydomain.com < /dev/null
mail: Null message body; hope that's ok
```

I simply need receive email if Cron task fails. Does Anyone have idea how to do It?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV PATH /usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install apt-transport-https gnupg -y dirmngr ca-certificates --no-install-recommends && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7 \
        && apt-get update && apt-get install syslog-ng apache2 apache2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev sudo curl build-essential ca-certificates \
        logrotate libpq5 make libyaml-0-2 cron supervisor libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev less nano git htop openssh-client mailutils --no-install-recommends -y \
        && a2enmod cache && a2enmod cache_disk && a2enmod expires && a2enmod headers && a2dismod mpm_event && a2enmod mpm_worker && a2dismod autoindex -f

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY logrotate.conf /etc/logrotate.conf
COPY syslog-ng.conf /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
COPY syslog-ng.logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
COPY apache2.logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
COPY apache2.server.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/server.conf
COPY apache2.sms_server.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sms_server.conf
COPY apache2.passenger.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf
COPY apache2.mpm_worker.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf
COPY run.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: Containers are usually a cut down version of the base OS, so I don't think the sendmail deamon would be running, you should be able to confirm this if you have `top` installed.  I'm not a linux guru, but I think you could maybe start the deamon from inside the container with -> `/etc/init.d/sendmail start`

Answer (score 0):

So I never got work sending emails inside docker container. This is my tmp. solutsion to this problem - using gmail.

```
apt-get install mailutils
apt-get install ssmtp
```

**/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf**

```
root=myerros@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=myerros@gmail.com
AuthPass=PasswordHere
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```